# How to prove this high-degree inequality

Tags: inequalities, gm.general-mathematics

Let $x$,$y$,$z$ be positive real numbers which satisfy $xyz=1$. Prove that:
$(x^{10}+y^{10}+z^{10})^2 \geq 3(x^{13}+y^{13}+z^{13})$.

And there is a similar question: Let $x$,$y$,$z$ be positive real numbers which satisfy the inequality
$(2x^4+3y^4)(2y^4+3z^4)(2z^4+3x^4) \leq(3x+2y)(3y+2z)(3z+2x)$. Prove this inequality:
$xyz\leq 1$.

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to prove these inequalities and how they arose?

Comment: Also, maybe wait a little bit between questions. You have asked two in quick succession.

Comment: thank you for your question,I asked the two question just out  of  curosity, neither for examination nor profit propose.I met this two questions online,here is the link, and I translate it to English. https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/w9_isyUk5ie0Oo69c7g9lg

Comment: OK, fair enough. It is good to give the source, if the question is not original to you. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These inequalities are algebraic and thus can be proved purely algorithmically.

Mathematica takes a minute or two for this proof of your first inequality:

[image: notebook 1]

---

Here is a "more human" proof:

Substituting $z=\frac1{xy}$, rewrite your first inequality as
\begin{equation}
    f(x,y)\mathrel{:=}\left(\frac{1}{x^{10} y^{10}}+x^{10}+y^{10}\right)^2-3 \left(\frac{1}{x^{13} y^{13}}+x^{13}+y^{13}\right)\ge0
\end{equation}
and then as
\begin{align}
g(x,y)&\mathrel{:=}f(x,y)x^{20} y^{20} \\ 
&=x^{40} y^{20}-3 x^{33} y^{20}+2 x^{30} y^{30}+x^{20} y^{40}-3 x^{20} y^{33} \\ 
&+2 x^{20} y^{10}+2 x^{10}
   y^{20}-3 x^7 y^7+1\ge0,
\end{align}
for $x,y>0$.

Further,
\begin{align}
g_1(x,y)\mathrel{:=}{}\frac{g'_x(x,y)}{x^6 y^7}&=40 x^{33} y^{13}-99 x^{26} y^{13}+60 x^{23} y^{23}+20 x^{13} y^{33} \\ 
&-60 x^{13} y^{26}+40 x^{13} y^3+20 x^3
   y^{13}-21, \\
g_2(x,y)\mathrel{:=}\frac{g'_y(x,y)}{x^7 y^6}&=20 x^{33} y^{13}-60 x^{26} y^{13}+60 x^{23} y^{23}+40 x^{13} y^{33} \\ 
&-99 x^{13} y^{26}+20 x^{13} y^3+40 x^3
   y^{13}-21,
\end{align}
and the only positive roots of the resultants of $g_1(x,y)$ and $g_2(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ are $y=1$ and $x=1$, respectively. So, $(1,1)$ is the only critical point of $g$.

Next, all the coefficients of the polynomial $g(1+u,1+v)$ in $u,v$ are nonnegative. Therefore and because of the symmetry $x\leftrightarrow y$, it remains to consider the cases (i) $0\le x\le1$ and $y>0$ is large enough and (ii) $x=0$.

For case (i), we have $g(x,y)\ge1 - 3 x^7 y^7 + 2 x^{10} y^{20}>0$. For case (ii), we have $g(0,y)=1>0$.

So, your first inequality is proved, again.

---

It took Mathematica about 1.8 hours to prove your second inequality (click on the image to enlarge it):

[image: notebook 2]

The latter proof would probably take many thousands pages.

Comment: What does "$y = \infty-$" mean?

Comment: @LSpice : I have replaced that by "$y>0$ is large enough".

Comment: [Thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385942/how-to-prove-this-high-degree-inequality/385961#comment983824_385961)!  Just so that it's here in fulltext:  the first Mathematica command is `Reduce[(x^(10)+y^(10)+z^(10))^2<3(x^(13)+y^(13)+z^(13))&&x>0&&y>0&&z>0&&x y z>1,{x,y,z},Reals]`, and the second is `Reduce[(2x^4+3y^4)(3x^4+2z^4)(2y^4+3z^4)<=(3x+2y)(3y+2z)(2z+3z)&&x>0&&y>0&&z>0&&x y z>1,{x,y,z},Reals]//AbsoluteTiming`.  Since the inequalities seem to be true (at least, you prove the first one), what does it mean that Mathematica returns `False`?

Comment: @LSpice : Both "inequalities" are actually implications of the form $C:=(A\implies B)$. In both cases, I asked Mathematica to Reduce[] the negation $\neg C=(A\ \&\ \neg B)$ of the implication $C$ (where $\neg$ is the negation symbol, $A$ is an equality or an inequality, and $B$ is an inequality). In both cases, Mathematica Reduce[]'d the negation $\neg C$ of $C$ to False. So, $C$ is true.

Comment: thank you for your detailed solution and explaination. the application of calculus  is awesome.it's so amzing to use Mathematica  to prove or disprove inequality.Never have I realised that this software can be so powerful.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a little less computer-assisted approach to both inequalities than the one suggested by Iosif Pinelis. Namely, I use the properties of rational one-variable functions which are seen from their graphs without thinking about how to prove them rigorously.

1. Fix $xyz=1$ and $x^{10}+y^{10}+z^{10}:=S$. Look for a maximum of $x^{13}+y^{13}+z^{13}$. It is achieved (the set of admissible triples is compact), and at the maximum points the gradients of $xyz,x^{10}+y^{10}+z^{10},x^{13}+y^{13}+z^{13}$ are linearly dependent, that is, we should have $$\alpha\cdot(yz,xz,xy)+\beta\cdot 10(x^9,y^9,z^9)+\gamma\cdot 13(x^{12},y^{12},z^{12})=0$$
   where the real coefficients $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ are not simultaneously zero. This means that all numbers $x,y,z$ solve the same equation $f(t):=a+bt^{10}+ct^{13}=0$, where $a=\alpha xyz$, $b=10\beta$, $c=13\gamma$. Such an equation may have at most two different positive solutions by [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs). That is, two of $x,y,z$ must be equal. Without loss of generality we may assume that $y=x$, then $z=1/x^2$ and we should prove a 1-variable inequality $$(2x^{10}+x^{-20})^2\geqslant 3(2x^{13}+x^{-26}).$$
   I do not see any nice explanation why this is true, but looking at the graphs we see that the ratio of exponents 13:10 may be increased to approximately 1.4047 (you may see that [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%282x%2Bx%5E%28-2%29%29%5E2-3%282x%5E%281.4047%29%2Bx%5E%28-2*1.4047%29%29%2C+x%3D0.8..1.1) graph is above the x-axis, but for the value of parameter 1.4048 it crosses it already.
2. Denote $a=y/x,b=z/y,c=x/z$. Then $abc=1$ and we are given $(xyz)^4(2+3a^4)(2+3b^4)(2+3c^4)\leqslant xyz(3+2a)(3+2b)(3+2c)$. Thus for establishing $xyz\leqslant 1$ it suffices (and is actually necessary) to check that $$(3+2a)(3+2b)(3+2c)\leqslant (2+3a^4)(2+3b^4)(2+3c^4) \quad (1)$$
   whenever $a,b,c$ are positive numbers with $abc=1$. (1) is equivalent to
   $$
   F(a,b,c):=h(a)+h(b)+h(c)\geqslant 0, \,\, \text{where}\,\, h(x):=\log(2+3x^4)-\log(3+2x).
   $$
   First of all, I claim that $F$ attains its minimal value on the set $\Omega:=\{(a,b,c):abc=1, a,b,c>0\}$. Indeed, consider a sequence $(a_n,b_n,c_n)$ for which $F(a_n,b_n,c_n)$ approaches the infimum of $F$ on $\Omega$. Since $h(x)$ is bounded from below on $(0,\infty)$ and tends to $+\infty$ for large $x$, we conclude that $a_n,b_n,c_n$ must be bounded, then we may choose a convergent subsequence and get a minimizer. So, denote the minimizer by $(a_0,b_0,c_0)$. the gradients of $F(a,b,c)$ and $abc$ at the point $(a_0,b_0,c_0)$ must be linearly dependent, thus we may write $h'(a_0)=\lambda b_0c_0$, $h'(b_0)=\lambda a_0c_0$, $h'(c_0)=\lambda b_0a_0$ for certain real $\lambda$. In other words, the function $g(x):=xh'(x)$ takes the same value at points $a_0,b_0,c_0$. Looking at the [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x*%28log%282%2B3x%5E4%29-log%283%2B2x%29%29%27%2C%20x%3D0..5) of $g(x)$ for positive $x$ we see that it takes each value at most twice. Thus two of three variables $a_0,b_0,c_0$ must be equal. Without loss of generality $a_0=b_0=:x$, $c_0=1/x^2$, and we should prove a 1-variable polynomial inequality $$(2+3x^4)^2(2+3/x^8)\geqslant (3+2x)^2(3+2/x^2)\quad \text{for}\quad x>0.$$
   Well, it follows from [factorization](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%20%282%2B3x%5E4%29%5E2%282%2B3%2Fx%5E8%29-%283%2B2x%29%5E2%283%2B2%2Fx%5E2%29).

Answer (score 4):

**Here is a simple proof**:

By [Chebyshev sum inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chebyshev%27s_Inequality) and AM-GM, we have
\begin{align*}
    x^{13}x^{1/3} + y^{13}y^{1/3} + z^{13}z^{1/3}
    &\ge \frac13(x^{13} + y^{13} + z^{13})(x^{1/3} + y^{1/3} + z^{1/3})\\
    &\ge \frac13(x^{13} + y^{13} + z^{13})\cdot 3\sqrt[3]{x^{1/3}y^{1/3}z^{1/3}}\\
    &= x^{13} + y^{13} + z^{13}. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

Then, it suffices to prove that
$$(x^{10}+y^{10}+z^{10})^2 \geq 3(x^{13+\frac13}+y^{13 + \frac13}+z^{13+ \frac13}). \tag{2}$$

Letting $x = a^{3/10}, y = b^{3/10}, z = c^{3/10}$, it suffices to prove that, for all $a, b, c > 0$ with $abc = 1$,
$$(a^3 + b^3 + c^3)^2 \ge 3(a^4 + b^4 + c^4). \tag{3}$$

We have
\begin{align*}
    &(a^3 + b^3 + c^3)^2 - 3(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)\\
    ={}& a^6 + b^6 + c^6 + 2a^3b^3 + 2b^3c^3 + 2c^3a^3 - 3(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)\\
    \ge{}& a^6 + b^6 + c^6 + (3a^2b^2 - 1) + (3b^2c^2 - 1) + (3c^2a^2 - 1)  - 3(a^4 + b^4 + c^4) \tag{4}\\
    ={}& a^6 + b^6 + c^6 + 3a^2b^2 + 3b^2c^2 + 3c^2a^2 - 3a^4 - 3b^4 - 3c^4 - 3\\
    ={}& a^6 + b^6 + c^6 + 3a^2b^2 + 3b^2c^2 + 3c^2a^2 - 3a^4 - 3b^4 - 3c^4 - 3a^2b^2c^2\\
    ={}& (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 3)(a^4 + b^4 + c^4 -a^2b^2 - b^2c^2 - c^2a^2)\\
    \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
where we use $2a^3b^3 - (3a^2b^2 - 1) = (2ab + 1)(ab - 1)^2 \ge 0$ in (4).

We are done.

Answer (score 3):

Another way. By my previous post it's enough to prove that:
$$(x^5+y^5+z^5)^2\geq3xyz(x^7+y^7+z^7)$$ for positive $x$, $y$ and $z$.

Indeed, let $x^5+y^5+z^5=\text{constant}$ and $x^7+y^7+z^7=\text{constant}$.

Thus, by the Vasc's EV Method (see here: [Cîrtoaje - The equal variable method](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/article828.html?sid=828) Corollary 1.8(b)) it's enough to prove the last inequality (because it's homogeneous) for $y=z=1$, which gives
$$(x^5+2)^2\geq3x(x^7+2)$$ or
$$(x-1)^2(x^8+2x^7-2x^5-4x^4-2x^3+2x+4)\geq0$$ and the rest is smooth.

Answer (score 3):

For the **first inequality**, let us write $x=X^3$, $y=Y^3$, $z=Z^3$, and pass to a homogenized version of it, obtained by multiplying the R.H.S. with $(xyz)^{7/3}=(XYZ)^7$. So we have to show:
$$
(X^{30}+Y^{30}+Z^{30})^2 \ge 3 (X^{39}+Y^{39}+Z^{39})X^7Y^7Z^7\ .
$$
Now divide by $Z^{60}$ to dehomogenize, so it is enough to show the above for $Z=1$ and arbitrary $X,Y\ge 0$. Consider the difference function
$$
f(X,Y)=
(X^{30}+Y^{30}+1)^2 - 3 (X^{39}+Y^{39}+1)X^7Y^7\ .
$$
Since $f(1,1)=0$ and on the boundary $XY=0$ we have $f(X,Y)\ge 1$,
a global minimal value is a local minimum in the domain $Y,Y>0$. We search such local minima, they are among the solutions of $f'(X,Y)=0$, which leads to
the algebraic system of equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
2(X^{30}+Y^{30}+1)\cdot 30X^{29}
&= 3 (46X^{45}Y^7 + 7X^6Y^{46}+7X^6Y^7)\ ,\\
2(X^{30}+Y^{30}+1)\cdot 30Y^{29}
&= 3 (46Y^{45}X^7 + 7Y^6X^{46}+7Y^6X^7)\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Now multiply the first equation with $X$, the second with $Y$. This leads to
$$
2(X^{30}+Y^{30}+1)\cdot 30X^{30}
= 3 (46X^{46}Y^7 + 7X^7Y^{46}+7X^7Y^7)
= 2(X^{30}+Y^{30}+1)\cdot 30Y^{30}
\ .
$$
So a solution must satisfy $X=Y$. We plug in this into the above, get
$$
2(2X^{30}+1)\cdot 30X^{30}
= 3 (53X^{53}+7X^{14})
\ .
$$
It turns out that $X=1$ is the only real positive root. So $(X,Y)=(1,1)$ is the only critical point. So it is the point where $f$ is globaly minimal.

---

The **second point** follows from the inequality
$$
(2x^4+3y^4)(2y^4+3z^4)(2z^4+3x^4) \ge (3x+2y)(3y+2z)(3z+2x)x^3y^3z^3\ .
$$
Let us show the above. After we expand, it is enough to show the domination
$$
12 \, \sum x^{8} y^{4} + 18 \sum \,  y^{8} x^{4} 
\ge 
18 \, \sum x^{5} y^{4} z^{3} + 12 \sum\, x^{5} y^{3} z^{4}  \ .
$$
To have a better view, let us place the points $(i,j,k)$ corresponding to the monomials $x^iy^jz^k$ that occur in the plane $i+j+k=12$.

[image: mathoverflow 385942]

Now, a simple human scheme of domination can be found, for instance exploiting:
$$
\begin{aligned}
12(5,3,4) &= 5(8,4,0)+ 2(0,8,4) + 5(4,0,8)\ ,\\
12(5,4,3) &= 5(4,8,0)+ 2(0,4,8) + 5(8,0,4)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now using the Jensen-convexity of the logarithm in the form $au+bv+cw\ge u^av^bw^c$ for $u,v,w>0$ and weights $a,b,c>0$ with total sum $a+b+c=1$, for the above suggested weights $a=c=5/12$, $b=2/12$, and the monomials $u=x^8y^4$, $v=y^8z^4$, $w=z^8x^4$ for the first line, then the reversed version for the second line, gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
12\,x^5y^3z^4 &\le 5\,x^8y^4 + 2\,y^8z^4 + 5\,z^8x^4\ ,\\
12\,x^5y^4z^3 &\le 5\,x^4y^8 + 2\,y^4z^8 + 5\,z^4x^8\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

This concludes the needed domination.

Comment: The second one is nice.

Answer (score 2):

This is to complement the nice answer by Fedor Petrov by a calculus proof of 
the inequality
$$ (2 x^{10} + x^{-20})^2\ge3 (2 x^{13} + x^{-26}),$$
for real $x>0$.

Rewrite this inequality as
$$f(x):=4 x^{60}-6 x^{53}+4 x^{30}-3 x^{14}+1\ge0.$$
Let
$$f_1(x):=\frac{f'(x)}{6x^{13}}=40 x^{46}-53 x^{39}+20 x^{16}-7,\\f_2(x):=\frac{f_1'(x)}{x^{15}}=1840 x^{30}-2067 x^{23}+320,\\
f_3(x):=\frac{f_2'(x)}{69x^{22}}=800 x^7-689.$$
Then, clearly, $f_2$ attains its minimum (on $[0,\infty)$) at $(689/800)^{1/7}$, and this minimum is $24.7\ldots>0$. So, $f_2>0$ and hence $f_1$ is increasing, from $f_1(0)=-7<0$ to $f_1(\infty-)=\infty>0$. Also, $f_1(1)=0$. So, $f_1\le0$ on $[0,1]$ and $f_1\ge0$ on $[1,\infty)$. So, $f$ attains its minimum (on $[0,\infty)$) at $1$, and this minimum is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

We'll prove a stronger inequality:

> $$\left(a^{10}+b^{10}+c^{10}\right)^2\geq3(a^{14}+b^{14}+c^{14}),$$ where $abc=1,$

for which it's enough to prove that
$$(x^5+y^5+z^5)^2\geq3xyz(x^7+y^7+z^7)$$ for positives $x$, $y$ and $z$.

Indeed, let $x=\min\{x,y,z\}$, $y=x+u$ and $z=x+v$.

Hence, $$\left(x^5 + y^5 + z^5\right)^2-3xyz\left(x^7 +y^7 + z^7\right)=$$
$$=(u^2-uv+v^2)x^8+8(-u^3+2u^2v+2uv^2-v^3)x^7+$$
$$+4(5u^4-17u^3v+50u^2v^2-17uv^3+5v^4)x^6+$$
$$+8(11u^5-20u^4v+25u^2v^2+25u^2v^3-20uv^4+11v^5)x^5+$$
$$+2(63u^6-79u^5v+50u^4v^2+100u^3v^3+50u^2v^4-79uv^5+63u^6)x^4+$$
$$+4(24u^7-21u^6v+5u^5v^2+25u^4v^3+25u^3v^4+5u^2v^5-21uv^6+24v^7)x^3+$$
$$+2(21u^8-12u^7v+10u^5v^3+25u^4v^4+10u^3v^5-12uv^7+21v^8)x^2+$$
$$+(10u^9-3u^8v+10u^5v^4+10u^4v^5-3uv^8+10v^9)x+(u^5+v^5)^2\geq$$
$$\geq\left((u^2-uv+v^2)x^2-8(u+v)(u^2-3uv+v^2)x+4(5u^4-17u^3v+50u^2v^2-17uv^3+5v^4)\right)x^6.$$

Let $u^2+v^2=tuv$.

Hence, $t\geq2$ and it remains to prove that $$(t-1)(5t^2-17t+40)-4(t+2)(t-3)^2\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$(t-1)(5t^2-17t+40)-4(t+2)(t-3)^2=$$
$$=t^3-6t^2+69t-112=t(t-3)^2+60t-112\geq0.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$x^{14}+y^{14}+z^{14}\geq x^{13}+y^{13}+z^{13},$$ where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives such that $xyz=1$, or
$$x^{42}+y^{42}+z^{42}\geq (x^{39}+y^{39}+z^{39})xyz,$$ which is true by Muirhed because
$$(42,0,0)\succ(40,1,1).$$

Answer (score 1):

This is to give an alternative proof of the inequality in Fedor Petrov's nice [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/386035)
$$(2 x^{10} + x^{-20})^2\ge3 (2 x^{13} + x^{-26})$$
for all $x > 0$.

We have
\begin{align*}
    &2x^{13+1/3} + x^{-26-2/3} - (2x^{13} + x^{-26})\\
    ={}& 2(x^{13+1/3} - x^{13}) + (x^{-13-1/3} - x^{-13})
    (x^{-13-1/3} + x^{-13})\\
    ={}& x^{13}(x^{1/3}-1)(2 - x^{-119/3} - x^{-118/3})\\
    \ge{}& 0.
\end{align*}

Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$(2 x^{10} + x^{-20})^2\ge 3(2x^{13+1/3} + x^{-26-2/3}).$$

Letting $x = a^{3/10}$, it suffices to prove that, for all $a > 0$,
$$(2a^3 + a^{-6})^2 \ge 3(2a^4 + a^{-8}).$$

We have
\begin{align*}
    &(2a^3 + a^{-6})^2 - 3(2a^4 + a^{-8})\\
    ={}& 4a^6 + 4a^{-3}+ a^{-12} - 6a^4 - 3a^{-8}\\
    \ge\,& 4a^6 + 2(3a^{-2} - 1) + a^{-12}  - 6a^4 - 3a^{-8}\\
    ={}& \frac{(2a^2+1)(2a^{12} - 2a^6 + 1)(a^2-1)^2}{a^{12}}\\
    \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
where we have used
$2a^{-3} - (3a^{-2} - 1) = \frac{(a+2)(a-1)^2}{a^3} \ge 0$.

We are done.

Comment: TeX note: in an `{align}` environment, as you know, `= & …` at the beginning of a line results in no space after the `=`.  You manually inserted a space `\,`, but it is probably preferable to insert an empty atom `{}` after the `=` which tricks it into spacing correctly itself.  While adding a link to @FedorPetrov's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/386035) that you reference, I edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice Thank you!